# Corruption on hardmode

Tags: terraria

[image]

So I have 2 questions:
1: Will the wall hold off the corruption (the wall is wood, stone brick, stone brick and wood)
2: What are the chances of corruption spawning (when I enter hardmode) on the other side of the wall?

Comment: I'd advise you to simply not mind about it, build a small wall around your base and let the corruption and the hallow be. If you want a place to call home you can create a new world, place sunflowers and never go to hard mode in that one.

Answer (score 4):

1: Your wall will prevent the [Corruption](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/The_Corruption) from spreading from one side to the other, yes. [Wood](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Wood) and [Gray Brick](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Gray_Brick) are [incorruptible](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/The_Corruption#Hardmode) (even in [Hardmode](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Hardmode)), and 4 blocks is the recommended wall width for preventing its spread.

2: There is, however, a chance that either [Corruption](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/The_Corruption) or [Hallow](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/The_Hallow) will cross your wall when Hardmode begins. The game will [convert large sections of your map](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Hardmode) into Corruption and Hallow as soon as the [Wall of Flesh](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Wall_of_Flesh) is defeated, which may span across both sides of your wall. Additionally, each time you destroy a [Demon Altar](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Altar), a small pocket of Corruption or Hallow will [appear in a random location](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Altar#Hardmode) on your map, and spread from there. This could happen on either side of your wall, or within the Jungle itself.

If your aim is to protect your [Jungle](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Jungle), I would suggest using [powders](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Thrown_Powder) to neutralize any conversions made there upon engaging Hardmode, and refrain from destroying any Demon Altars on this map.

Comment: Thanks lol, although I played terraria for a long time I didnt know that pockets of corruption/crimson were created upon the destroying of a demon alter

Answer (score 0):

No, you are not safe. The corruption can spawn right at the edge of your jungle, crossing over the wall; after the initial burst, destroying demon altars has a chance to create corruption inside the wall, or on the other side of the jungle, near the ocean.

If, however, after breaking all demon altars you're going to, you'll find that all of the corruption is on the safe side on the wall, then yes, the jungle will be safe.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, the wall will be able to prevent the Corruption from spreading beyond that point. However, if your world is a Large World, There may be another Corruption or Crimson in that world that may infect your Jungle from the other side before you have time to place a second wall.